# WebSearch Stopped Working

Tags: web-access, webservices, error-tracking, webtools

I've been using 'WebSearch' and 'WebImageSearch' quite a lot recently to sample images for my work. However, these functions suddenly stopped working. When I evaluate, for example,

```
WebImageSearch["plant"]
```

I simply get the same thing

```
Out[]= WebImageSearch["plant"]
```

This happens even when I take a specific search engine, by setting, for example, `Method -> "Google"`. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you run out of `$ServiceCreditsAvailable`?

Comment: @b3m2a1 No, what is that? I ran and it returned 2.

Comment: the APIs Mathematica connects too aren’t always free. This is how Mathematica lets you buy more access (if you want to). You start with like 200/mo or something

Comment: Oh that's interesting. I didn't know about it. Do you know of any alternatives for image api's from google or somewhere else?

Comment: For example, something like `Import[url, "Images"]`, though with Google I can only get the miniatures..

Comment: Please remove the [tag:bugs] tag if this is not a bug